# XMLEventWriter: how can I tell it to write empty elements?

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I do not see an option within `javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter` or `javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory` to set either up in a way so that empty elements are written (instead of explicit start and end element pairs).

I see that Woodstox has a property to do this, but it is not standardized.

Am I missing any obvious way to do this?

Comment: `<x></x>` *is* an empty element.

Comment: Of course you are quite right.  I should have been more specific, since I obviously wasn't clear here.  What I mean is, an element that ends with "/>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no semantic difference between `<x/>` and `<x></x>` and the standard APIs do not provide a way to request one or the other.

Comment: An implementation detail of the StAX writer included with the JDK by default: calling `writeStartElement("localname");writeEndElement()` results in a self-closing tag, while calling `writeStartElement("localname");writeCharacters(null);writeEndElement()` results in an opening tag immediately followed by a closing tag.

Comment: As you note, that is an implementation detail.  Other serializers and later versions of StAX may or may not do this.

Comment: I just have an issue where JAXB chokes on `<xi:include href="somePatch/someXml"></xi:include>` but is fine with `<xi:include href="somePatch/someXml"/>`. So there seems to be a semantic difference? Or is it a bug in JAXB?

Answer (score 7):

```
writer.writeEmptyElement("some_element");
writer.writeAttribute("some_attribute", "some_value");
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting property so that empty tags are generated like `<x/>` works with WoodStox APIs:

```
WstxOutputFactory factory = new WstxOutputFactory();
factory.setProperty(WstxOutputFactory.P_AUTOMATIC_EMPTY_ELEMENTS, true);
```

I wanted indentation in XML tags. the setIndentation method is working with neither javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory nor org.codehaus.stax2.XMLOutputFactory2

Answer (score 3):

In several of the answers and comments there is some confusion.

StAX has two APIs:

- The "Cursor API" using `XMLStreamReader` and `XMLStreamWriter`; and
- The "Iterator API" using `XMLEventReader` and`XMLEventWriter`;

Outputting an empty element with a single tag, `<example/>`, **is** possible with the *Cursor API* using`XMLStreamWriter`:

```
xmlStreamWriter.writeEmptyElement("example");
```

Outputting an empty element with a single tag, `<example/>`, **is not** possible with the *Iterator API* using `XMLEventWriter`, as far as I know. In this case you're stuck with producing an empty element with two tags `<example></example>`:

```
xmlEventWriter.add(xmlEventFactory.createStartElement("", null, "example"));
xmlEventWriter.add(xmlEventFactory.createEndElement("", null, "example"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably know this already, but XMLStreamWriter does have method for specifying that it should be "real" empty element. XMLEventWriter is missing a few pieces that lower level interface has.